# How to implement custom GIF activityIndicator in Appcelerator Titanium?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

I want to implement custom activity indicator in iOS app. I'm using Appcelerator Titanium in MVC framework.

Answer (score 2):

you can implementer custom activity indicateur on use ImageView.images

You need to generate all images of your GIF in png / jpg and set it to

```
ImageView.images = ["/images/img1.png", "/images/img2.png" ....."/images/imgN.png"]
```

you can set the interval of image transition and start / stop the animation

[Documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ImageView-property-images)

Comment: Somewhat anecdotal, but look at a memory profile for your app before and after adding an animated image in this way. About half a year ago I used this approach to add a new animated icon to one of my apps, and my memory usage went through the roof. I don't remember if it was iOS or Android... like I said, anecdotal. :\